# .htaccess entry to return simple text based on the URI

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, querystring

I have URL `http://foo.com/bar?abc=123`, what would be the correct entry in the `htaccess` file to return a simple text 200 status of `abc=123`? Basically, I just want to return the entire query string as simple text.

I know return ing text is possible because I have used it with `ErrorDocument` before, and I know accessing the query is possible with `QUERY_STRING`, I just don't know how to combine the two in a `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to do this with Apache, but I did find a simple way with php.

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];  // Given GET /foo/bar?query, output: query
?>
```